# Google Translate API always returning 'Daily Limit Exceeded'

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I'm trying to get the google translate API up and running. On the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started), it gives the following example: `https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?key={MyAppId}&q=google+translate+is+fast`

I just want to get this working for now, so I'm just trying to get it working view via a browser post, so I created a testing web application (screenshot):

[image: Settings]

and grabbed the API key, replaced the sample URL's key with my API key. I get the following response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

I should also note, that I have signed my account up with the billing option (I plan on using the service quite a bit), so I should have no issues at the moment.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't know what. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For getting data translated you have to enable billing and have to register your credit/debit card.After you register your card 1$ will be deducted and then you will be able to use your URL

I did it recently and it worked fine.

I am also working on translating project nowadays.

Let me know if you need any kind of help on this topic

Ishan

Comment: i ran my first query and it gave me this error. Please help

Comment: So, is it necessary to buy a paid plan to just use Translate API?

Answer (score 3):

I would first confirm that the Translate API is enabled under the "APIs" link in the Cloud Console - if it is not enabled, that effectively sets the quota to zero and may produce a similar message.

If the API is enabled, then the following link describes how to check the usage limits for your project:
https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing

Answer (score 3):

You can change the quotas manually:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to complement @Ishan Arora, after you add the credit card info, go to the console, enter into the project, a message will popup asking to setup the billing account for your project, if you want to get ride of the error, just select "set project into the billing account" drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

On my case, the same problem was caused by credit card expiration