# Issue in Google Translate API

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I have registered for Google developer console today. I created a project in this console. After that I enabled API for Google Translate API. Got a key from Google for it. 
Now I am trying to test a simple program given in below link. I have replaced dummy key in this program with actual key.

[Programm link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#JSONP).

I am getting below error in return from Google API service. What could be going wrong here?

```
// API callback
translateText({
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Translate API always returning 'Daily Limit Exceeded'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048735/google-translate-api-always-returning-daily-limit-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error says it all: you have exceeded your daily limit of calls to the API.
You have to enable billing: https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#setup

Comment: Actually I started using this service today only. I am getting this error on first call to Google Translation service. So not sure what's going wrong. Can anyone please guide?

Comment: Apparently you have to enable billing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048735/google-translate-api-always-returning-daily-limit-exceeded

Comment: Thanks Rian for your help!! Appreciate it :-)