# Trying to install and use a 3rd party java translation api Linux Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am an enthusiast programmer trying to make a simple program that implements a 3rd party API used for translation of language, such as Google Translate.

I have searched for a long time, but what I have read has gone over my head, for I am still a novice in programming and computer use. I would love clear-cut instructions on how I can get a download of the API, install(?) it, and use its code in my code, if that is possible. This is what I want, but if it does not work that way, let me know!

I do ***not*** use an IDE for development, and I run Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pardon my lengthy answer, hope it may help you achieve what you are trying to do.

There is a Java port of Google Translate available [here](https://github.com/richmidwinter/google-api-translate-java).

The example program given there looks simple, i have added few modifications to it:

```
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;
import com.google.api.GoogleAPI;

public class JTranslator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Set the HTTP referrer to your website address.
    GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http://duckduckgo.com");

    // Set the Google Translate API key
    // See: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html
    GoogleAPI.setKey("hSifeHtllArOfSknahTgNoLo-SyXaLago-TeDIuGsReki-HhctIH");

    String translatedText = Translate.DEFAULT.execute("Bonjour le monde", Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);

    System.out.println(translatedText);
  }
}
```

But in order to execute the above simple program, we need Google Translate API key. It requires us to create a project in [Google Developers](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and create a key against that project. It's a lengthy process, so instead of uploading all the steps(in images) here, the images have been uploaded [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVZaL.jpg).

Once we have the API Key, next comes the execution part. We need to download the [jar](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/downloads/list) file to use.

Let's assume we have java & the downloaded jar file in the same folder, following are the steps to compile and execute the program:

**Compile:**

```
javac -cp google-api-translate-java-0.97.jar;. JTranslator.java
```

**Execute:**

```
java -cp google-api-translate-java-0.97.jar;. JTranslator
```

But while executing we will hit the following error:

```
Error: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.GoogleAPIException: java.lang.Exception: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving transla
tion.
        at com.google.api.translate.TranslateV2.execute(TranslateV2.java:68)
        at JTranslator.main(JTranslator.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.
        at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:99)
        at com.google.api.translate.TranslateV2.execute(TranslateV2.java:62)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key="hSifeHtllArOfSknahTgNoLo-SyXaLago-TeDIuGsReki-HhctIH&q=Bonjour+le+monde&target=en&source=fr
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:93)
        ... 2 more
```

The simplified version of this error can be retrieved if we copy paste the URL tried by the program into browser:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048735/google-translate-api-always-returning-daily-limit-exceeded) SOF question, it is clear that we need to pay for the usage of Translate API. There is also an option [Sign up for a free trial.](https://console.developers.google.com/freetrial) in Google Developers Console. [Google Translate pricing](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing).

Good luck.

**Update:**
Came across a [Translator API](http://www.microsoft.com/translator/getstarted.aspx) from Microsoft, which allows translation of upto 2Million Characters/month for free.

Comment: Thanks for the very step-by-step answer. I will try to accomplish this. :)

Comment: Do you know of any translation API that you don't need a key/pay for? If not, that fine, but I was just curious.

Comment: There were few open source APIs listed in Google search but the learning curve for it looked steep. For Google & Microsoft the implementation part looked straight forward once we got the API key. You can wait to see if someone can suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to incorporate the API into your Java code would be to use a build tool like Maven that automatically downloads the jar file and adds it as a dependency to your project. The following pom.xml snippet is taken directly from the Google Developers page for the Translate API:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-translate</artifactId>
      <version>v2-rev41-1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2